# CentOs Php and MySql Configuration

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I had php installed and running for awhile now but I am starting to work on a project in which to connect to a database (i.e mysql)  so i installed mysql (5.1.73)  and now when I go to connect to the database using this line

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
```

I get the following error:

```
1 Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/file.php
```

This leads me to believe my configuration of php isn't connected to my recently installed version of mysql.  I went to the config file (php.ini) that was listed in the `phpinfo()` call and added in extension="php_mysql.dll" just because that was what most forums seems to recommend.  After doing that I restarted (and reloaded the php.ini file I think)  by using the `service httpd restart` command.

Any recommendations?

Comment: in php you should use mysqli now http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: mysql has been deprecated in the newer versions of php. Use `mysqli_connect()` or use `PDO`. Read the documentation at http://www.php.net

Comment: Simply adding the line in PHP.INI won't help unless you actually have the required DLL on your system.

Comment: Sorry if I am mistaken but Centos (Unix) and *.dll ? I think something is wrong here!  *.dll files are for windows, .so is the correct extension for unix php extension files.

Comment: i removed the dll extension and noticed that when phpinfo is called in the configure command section it has '--without-mysql'  how can i Change this?

Comment: Related: [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in (Serverfault)](http://serverfault.com/q/379430/69499)

Answer (score 1):

If this is on centos do you have php-mysql package installed? By default php-mysql (the required files for mysql and mysqli) aren't installed with minimum installation.

yum install php-mysql

service httpd restart

Comment: I just installed php-mysql.  what do i have to do to configure it? I restarted httpd as well

Comment: It should work once installed, have you just tried it? What is the error now? try out phpinfo(); does it list mysql as installed? if so then it should work if not then there is another issue.

Comment: I have installed it and nothing :(  i still get the --without-mysql in the configure command section.

Comment: Do you have the file /etc/php.d/mysql.ini or mysqli.ini? You can try the command `yum list installed php*` from there what is listed?

Comment: I do have that file in that directory.

Comment: Look at Additional .ini files parsed is it parsing mysql.ini? If so then it's loading it, search the page for the section Mysql if that section exists then it works, if it doesn't then it's not working. Also take OUT extension="php_mysql.dll"  as that's for windows not  *nix